# Can I check if server is up without connecting to it?

Tags: bash, server, connection

Is it possible to check if a remote server is up, without connecting to it?

Basically, `telnet ip.ad.dre.ss port` works, but will connect to the server. Is there an equivalent command, that will **just check** is the server is up, without establishing a connection with it?

I would like to check it in a bash script.

Comment: You can use nmap or ping

Comment: remote or local? it's pretth hard to confirm a remote server is serving without connecting to it.

Comment: @Jasen remote server!

Comment: you should use `ping -c1 1.1.1.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server is a remote server you can not check without connecting to the server. You can only check that by log into the Operating System where that server is running and then you have to use `ps -ef | grep [p]rocessName`

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

For a local server `ss --listening`  will list all listening processes.

for a remote server you could connect using ssh and run ss, or test the listening socket(s) directly using `nmap`

`

Comment: So nmap would not connect to the socket? Would it simply tell if a socket is listening at the requested port?

Comment: nmap defaults to a SYN probe which is sort of half-connecting